# Tracking a bzr repository as a Git submodule

Tags: git, github, bazaar

I have a repository on GitHub which depends on two projects which are developed in Bazaar. Currently I just download and unpack sources, but it would be nice if I could actually keep their history. Is there a simple solution for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the history to be shared between Git and Bzr, consider using a third-party bi-directional bridge between Git and Bzr. There are many like [this](http://github.com/kfish/git-bzr) one.

**EDIT**: There's now a `git-remote-bzr` in contrib/ of git.git.  Use that.

Comment: git-bzr demonstrates how to have a bzr repository as a git *branch*, but how would one make this a git submodule?

Comment: Am I misunderstanding something? Use `git submodule` to make that repository with imported history a submodule in the main repository.

Comment: Here is a link for it: https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/contrib/remote-helpers/git-remote-bzr

Comment: `git-remote-bzr` is now maintained separately from git, and is available here: https://github.com/felipec/git-remote-bzr. Running `git submodule add bzr::REPO` with `git-remote-bzr` installed, however, fails with the error message "fatal: transport 'bzr' not allowed" for me (Git version 1.9.1).

Comment: @zrajm: `export GIT_ALLOW_PROTOCOL=file:git:http:https:ssh:bzr` fixes that issue. Submodules are restricted to prevent arbitrary command execution. See https://github.com/git/git/commit/33cfccbbf35a56e190b79bdec5c85457c952a021